# Poisson Kolmogorov Smirnov ties warning

Tags: r, goodness-of-fit

I am trying to run a KS test on a vector to check if its follows a Poisson distribution

```
require("MASS")

Data <- rpois(100000, 20)
distFit<-fitdistr(Data,"Poisson")
ks.test(Data,"ppois",lambda=distFit$estimate)
```

unfortunately I get the following message once I run ks.test in the next step

Warning message:
In ks.test(Data, "ppois", lambda = distFit$estimate) :
  ties should not be present for the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Not an answer, but note that you can only use the K-S-test to test for a *fully specified* distribution. If you use it to test whether your sample belongs to a distribution *with parameters estimated from the sample*, the critical values will be off. The K-S-test will be too conservative.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Stephan The error comes from the duplicated values in the vector (ie ks.test(unique(Data),"ppois",lambda=distFit$estimate) would work)

Answer (score 2):

you could apply the `jitter` function to your data to break ties ... have a look at `?jitter`to find out if it fits your needs